# how to set a boolean field in activiti

Tags: java, activiti

Im trying to set the `autoStoreVariables` field of a `org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.listener.ScriptTaskListener`.

This is the `userTask` containing a `taskListener`.

```
<userTask id="WorkJob.task" name="WorkJob.task" activiti:assignee="${assignee}" activiti:dueDate="${dueDate}">
    <extensionElements>
        <activiti:taskListener event="create" class="org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.listener.ScriptTaskListener" >
          <activiti:field name="autoStoreVariables" expression="${true}"/>
          <activiti:field name="script" stringValue="${out:print('hello world')}"/>
          <activiti:field name="language" stringValue="juel" />
        </activiti:taskListener>
    </extensionElements>
</userTask>
```

Getting the following error:

> org.activiti.engine.ActivitiIllegalArgumentException: Incompatible
>   type set on field declaration 'autoStoreVariables' for class
>   org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.listener.ScriptTaskListener. Declared
>   value has type org.activiti.engine.impl.el.JuelExpression, while
>   expecting boolean

I tried the following with no success:

```
<activiti:field name="autoStoreVariables" booleanValue="true"/>

<activiti:field name="autoStoreVariables" stringValue="true"/>

<activiti:field name="autoStoreVariables" expression="true"/>
```

What is the correct way to set a `boolean` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordint to the Activiti user guide [Field Injection](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/index.html#executionListenerFieldInjection) section

> It’s possible to inject values into the fields of the delegated
>   classes. The following types of injection are supported:
>
> - Fixed string values
> - Expressions

Looks like it is not possible to inject boolean value directly. I think in your case the solution is to extend `ScriptTaskListener`, e.g.

```
public class CustomScriptTaskListener extends ScriptTaskListener {

    private Expression autoStoreVariablesExp;

    public void setAutoStoreVariablesExp(Expression autoStoreVariablesExp) {
        this.autoStoreVariablesExp = autoStoreVariablesExp;
    }

    @Override
    public void notify(DelegateTask delegateTask) {
        autoStoreVariables = Boolean.TRUE.equals(autoStoreVariablesExp.getValue(delegateTask));

        super.notify(delegateTask);
    }
}
```

And inject value with `<activiti:field name="autoStoreVariablesExp" expression="${true}"/>`.